# python: best way convey missing value count

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, visualization, data-visualization

I currently have a data frame with 9 features and some features have missing values. I do the following to get the `count` of missing values in each feature:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

which gives me:

```
A           0
B           0
C    15844523
D         717
E       18084
F      118679
G           0
H      978505
I           0
```

I want to display this information in a nice way. I can always create a table in the report but is there any other way to display this in a plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.log`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.log(s).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: log]

Another solution is categorize data to bins by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and then use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#convert Series to one column df with column name 'name'
df = s.rename('name').to_frame()

bins = [-1,1, 10, 100, 1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000, 100000000,np.Inf]
labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
df['label'] = pd.cut(df['name'], bins=bins, labels=labels)

print (df.label)
A    0
B    0
C    8
D    3
E    5
F    6
G    0
H    6
I    0
Name: label, dtype: category
Categories (10, int64): [0 < 1 < 2 < 3 ... 6 < 7 < 8 < 9]

df.label.astype(int).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: binned graph]

I think it is nicer as plot column `name`:

```
df.name.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: orig]

Answer (score 4):

You can visualize the count of the missing values with vertical bars.

Use the pandas.DataFrame.plot() method :

```
df.isnull().sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

For more fancy plots you can use the python library
 [**plot.ly**](https://plot.ly/python/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno) library for cool visualizations:

```
 import missingno as msno 

 msno.matrix(df)
 msno.bar(df)
 msno.heatmap(df)
```

Look how easy we can find the sparcity of data!
[image]